# Handlbars - Can I limit certain helpers to being within other helpers?

Tags: handlebars.js, mustache

For example I want to use a nested helper like this:

```
{{#submission}}
     {{field}}
{{/submission}}
```

But I want `{{field}}` in this case to be a different helper from the one above

```
{{#post}}
     {{field}}
{{/post}}
```

and maybe even something else if used when not inside either of those (or perhaps just displaying data that passed, and not triggering a helper).

```
{{field}}
```

Is this possible, or do I have to make every helper unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry but every helper has to be unique. If you want to use a different code then you have to do it programmatically by handling a parameter and switching your code depending on your parameter.